# How to switch to PartialView A to PartialView B on interaction with PartialView A?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

There is a `ParentPage` which displays `PartialViewA` in the right pane. 
Within `PartialViewA` there is a dropdown. On selecting certain value I want to replace `PartialViewA` with `PartialViewB`. Is this possible? How do I go about it?

**I tried :**
(`PartialViewA`:)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('aa');
        $("#drpisEmpty").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "loaded") {
                alert($(this).val());
            }
            else {              
                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("PartialViewB", "ParentController", new { CargoType = "PartialViewA" })';

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**CallCargoTypePartialView:**(ParentController)

```
  public ActionResult CallCargoTypePartialView(string CargoType)
        {
            if (CargoType == "PartialViewA")
            {
                return View("_PartialViewA");
            }
            else if (CargoType == "PartialViewB")
            {
                return View("_PartialViewB");
            }
            return View("_PartialViewA");
        }
```

The problem I am facing is that when I call PartialViewA from within PartialViewB or vice verce, the entire page(along with parent) gets replaced with just the outout of PartialView.

Comment: You need to use ajax to call a server method which returns a partial view, and append it to the DOM in the success callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs in this line:

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("PartialViewB", "ParentController", new { CargoType = "PartialViewA" })';
```

By using [`location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location), you're replacing entire elements from existing page with the returned page from controller action, therefore the existing view is overwritten by new one.

Assumed that you have this setup:

```
<div id="partial">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialViewA")
</div>
```

Then you need to perform AJAX callback inside `else` block and append it inside `success` result marked by the placeholder of previous partial view, as like this example below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('aa');
        $("#drpisEmpty").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "loaded") {
                alert($(this).val());
            }
            else {              
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Action("CallCargoTypePartialView", "ParentController")',
                    data: { CargoType: "PartialViewB" }, // example passed data
                    success: function (result) {
                        // replace first partial view with the second one
                        $('#target').html(result);
                    },
                    error: function (...) {
                        // error handling
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also note that you should return `PartialView()` instead of `View()`:

```
public ActionResult CallCargoTypePartialView(string CargoType)
{
   if (CargoType == "PartialViewA")
   {
       return PartialView("_PartialViewA");
   }
   else if (CargoType == "PartialViewB")
   {
       return PartialView("_PartialViewB");
   }
   return PartialView("_PartialViewA");
}
```